# Http request with Hasura graphql not working

Tags: rest, graphql, httprequest, hasura

I'm a newbie to [Hasura](https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/core/api-reference/index.html#api-reference) and need a little help trying to pull data via an http request.

Below is my request but I don't think my syntax is correct. I need to pass ajson object where the key is query and the value is the code block. How do I do this?

Shawn

```
query MyQuery {
  t_user(where: {id: {_eq: "2"}}) {
    name
    id
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer with a little help. I needed to put my query into a JSON object. So my query in the console was this:
`query MyQuery { t_user(where: {id: {_eq: "2"}}) { name id } }`

And I needed to it to look like this:
`{"query":"query MyQuery {\n  t_user(where: {id: {_eq: \"2\"}}) {\n    name\n    id\n  }\n}\n","variables":null,"operationName":"MyQuery"}`

Comment: For what it's worth there is much better tooling available for making requests to GraphQL servers besides manually constructing the requests like this. This might be fine if you're just playing around this may be fine but I would strongly recommend that you take a look at something like Apollo Client or URQL depending on what kind of application you're building

Comment: Appreciated @JesseCarter. In this case I just needed a Post HTTP request for a scenario I have in [Integromat](https://www.integromat.com/). My next step is Apollo Client in a React app. Hopefully the learning curve isn't too steep.

Answer (score 0):

You should post your question with more details. Like **the actual code making the request to Hasura graphql endpoint**

Here's an example request using the **Browser `fetch` api**

```
const query = `query MyQuery {
  t_user {
    name
    id  
  }
}`;

fetch('https://lasting-grub-95.hasura.app/v1/graphql', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'x-hasura-admin-secret': 'my-secret'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        query
    })
})
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
        console.log('Hasura response: ', res);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
    })
```

For the **admin-secret** go to projects page of **[Hasura Cloud](https://cloud.hasura.io/projects)**. There you would see your project listed with necessary details including `Admin Secret`

Comment: just edited my question. I'm trying to test this in postman. Any help would be appreciated.